# Binding two ObservableObjects in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have two observable objects, one is a view model for the a view and the other is a data manager that manages various kinds of data in the app. I would like to bind a property in the data manager to a property in the view model.

Something like this

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Binding var mirroredStuff: [String]

    init(dataManager: DataManager) {
        // Is there any way to make this work?
        _mirroredStuff = dataManager.$stuff
    }
}

class DataManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var stuff: [String] = []

    func fetchStuff() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.stuff = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this sort of thing?

Comment: Why do you have such a design in the first place? Do you really need both of them to exist? Or at least, do you really need both of them to be `ObservableObject`s? Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: @Sweeper It's sort of the result of an app built by people that LOVE singletons and I'm working on refactoring it.

I want the view model to contain the logic that transforms data from the DataManager for display, but I need a way for the viewmodel to be updated when the data in the DataManager changes.

Comment: Okay, that sounds like `DataManager` doesn't need to be an `ObservableObject`. `stuff` can just be a `CurrentValueSubject` or some other publisher like that. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: In SwiftUI the `View` struct is the view model already so you can just remove your view model class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Binding` is for value types and can only be used in a `View`. It cannot be used in a `class`.

If the "Manager" uses `Combine` you can `assign` the values to the `@Published`.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var mirroredStuff: [String] = .init()

    init(dataManager: DataManager) {
        dataManager.stuff.assign(to: &$mirroredStuff)
    }
}
import Combine

class DataManager {
    var stuff: CurrentValueSubject<[String], Never> = .init([])

    init(){}
    func fetchStuff() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.stuff.send(["One", "Two", "Three"])
        }
    }
}
```

The `DataManager` should be the same instance as the part of the code that "fetches" the objects.

https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/dependency-injection/