# How can I bind to a published property of a singleton class in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it possible to create a `@Binding` var to a `@Published` property of a singleton class for use in a SwiftUI view? I need to reflect and possibly mutate this property from the view, but I want to avoid using the class as an `@ObservedObject` in a way so I don't have unnecessary view updates caused by mutation of other unrelated to this view published properties of the class. How can I achieve it?

I tried:

```
var someVar: Binding<String> = Binding.constant(SomeSingleton.shared.someProperty)
```

But it didn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78023270/binding-two-observableobjects-in-swiftui/78023415#78023415

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly you can have something like this.

```
class Singleton: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dummy1: Int = 0
    @Published var dummy2: Int = 0

    static var shared = Singleton()
}

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dummy1: Int = 0

    init () {
        Singleton.shared.$dummy1.assign(to: &$dummy1)
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = MyViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(viewModel.dummy1)")
    }
}
```