# Why Can't I Access the Environment Object from a Class in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have some code in which I am trying to access an environment object to call one of its methods from within a class. However, when I run the app I get the following error: SwiftUI/EnvironmentObject.swift:90: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type FavoritesStore found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for FavoritesStore may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

My code looks like so, with some methods and properties removed for brevity:

```
struct Special_ParakeetApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            BirdsListandFavoriteBirdsTabView()
                .environment(\.firebaseDatabase, Firestore.firestore())
                .environmentObject(FavoritesStore())
        }
    }
}

struct BirdDetailFavoriteButtonView: View {
    @ObservedObject var isFavorited: IsFavorited
    
    var body: some View {
        Label(
            title: { Text(isFavorited.bird.name) },
            icon: {
                Button {
                    withAnimation {
                        isFavorited.isFavorited.toggle()
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: isFavorited.isFavorited ? "heart.circle.fill" : "heart.circle")
                }}).font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.heavy)
    }
}

class IsFavorited: ObservableObject, Decodable  {
    @EnvironmentObject var favoritesStore: FavoritesStore

    var isFavorited: Bool = false {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
            Task { await makeFavorite(newValue) }
        }
    }

    func makeFavorite(_ isFavorited: Bool) async {
          await favoritesStore.changeFavorite(IsFavoritedDocumentMaker(collectionPath: FavoritesStoreCollection.isFavorited,
                                                                     birdName: bird.name,
                                                                     isFavorited: isFavorited))
    }
```

Why can't I access the environment object from inside my IsFavorited class so I can call a method on the class from an external view?

Comment: That property wrapper is only meant to be used instead SwiftUI views. You can still inject it yourself

Comment: You can access an environment object only within the body of a SwiftUI view. What you might be doing, is reading a `FavoritesStore`  object from an `@Environment` value in a parent view and passing it in its body to a child view which creates and initialises the `IsFavorite` observable, which provides this object either as an ready-to-use environment object, or passes it along to the next child view - your target view.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Do you mean that one way to resolve this might be by declaring @EnvironmentObject inside `BirdDetailFavoriteButtonView`, for example, and then declaring `FavoritesStore` as a property in `IsFavorited` and then initializing `isFavorited` with the value passed from the parent view?

Comment: No, you actually have to jump though a few more hoops to build a viable solution. Please, see my answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78023270/binding-two-observableobjects-in-swiftui/78023415#78023415

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you have to tackle a few more problems:

So, lets assume we first make a mock for the "favourites" store:

```
actor FavoritesStore<Item: Identifiable> {

    private var ids: Set<Item.ID>
    
    init(favorites: [Item] = []) {
        ids = Set(favorites.map { $0.id })
    }
    
    func favorites() -> Set<Item.ID> {
        ids
    }
    
    func add(itemId: Item.ID) {
        ids.insert(itemId)
    }
    
    func remove(itemId: Item.ID) {
        ids.remove(itemId)
    }
    
    func isFavorite(itemId: Item.ID) -> Bool {
        ids.contains(itemId)
    }
}
```

We also need the "Bird" struct:

```
struct Bird: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}
```

My suggestion now was to make the FavoritesStore an environment value, or better, make it part of a `Env` struct where you can keep all your dependencies:

```
struct Env {
    var favoritesStore = FavoritesStore<Bird>()
}


struct EnvKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: Env = .init()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var env: Env {
        get { self[EnvKey.self] }
        set { self[EnvKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Note, that `Env` is a struct and the store is a reference type.

Next, the Observable Object. This needs to reference the store and also takes an ID of the item - means, this observable is associated to a single Bird.

Here, the implementation follows some important principles, which when you violate it, you may get into troubles:

First, make the setter of the Published property *private*!
Second, never add `didSet` to the published property!

If you do the above, you may get into infinite recursions and it also becomes difficult to reason about the logic.

Instead provide an *extra* function where you send user intents to the observable and handle the logic in a clear way depending on the current state and the event that comes in, and then update your published properties.

```
@MainActor
final class IsFavorited: ObservableObject  {
    
    private let favoritsStore: FavoritesStore<Bird>
    private let itemId: Bird.ID
    
    @Published private(set) var isFavorited: Bool = false
    
    init(favoritsStore: FavoritesStore<Bird>, itemId: Bird.ID) {
        self.favoritsStore = favoritsStore
        self.itemId = itemId
        Task { @MainActor in
            self.isFavorited = await favoritsStore.isFavorite(
                 itemId: itemId
            )
        }
    }
    
    func setFavoriteStatus(_ status: Bool) {
        Task { @MainActor in
            switch status {
            case true:
                await favoritsStore.add(itemId: itemId)
            case false:
                await favoritsStore.remove(itemId: itemId)
            }
        }
        isFavorited = status
    }
    
}
```

Now, in order to read an environment this can only happen in the body of a view. Once you have the store, you initialise an Observable with it, then pass it to the view responsible for rendering the Button with the Icon.

You will need *three* views to accomplish this:

First, a view reading the environment:

```
public struct EnvironmentReader<Content: View, Env>: View {
    @Environment private var env: Env

    private let content: (Env) -> Content

    public init(
        _ keyPath: KeyPath<EnvironmentValues, Env>,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Env) -> Content
    ) {
        self._env = .init(keyPath)
        self.content = content
    }

    public var body: some View {
        content(env)
    }
}
```

Note, this view reads the environment value and passes it on to its "content" view, which is a child view. Here it is a *function* taking the `env` as a parameter and returning a view. Later, in your case, this will be the `BirdDetailFavoriteButtonView`, receiving a `@ObservedObject` object, where the `env` parameter was used to to initialise it (see the `ContentView` further below).

Next, the second view `BirdDetailFavoriteButtonView`:

```
struct BirdDetailFavoriteButtonView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: IsFavorited
    let bird: Bird
    
    @State var isFavorited: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        
        let isFavoritedBinding: Binding<Bool> = .init(
            get: { model.isFavorited },
            set: { status in
                model.setFavoriteStatus(status)
            }
        )
        
        Label(
            title: { Text(bird.name) },
            icon: {
                Button {
                    withAnimation {
                        isFavorited.toggle()
                        model.setFavoriteStatus(isFavorited)
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: isFavorited ? "heart.circle.fill" : "heart.circle")
                }
            }
        )
        .font(.title)
        .fontWeight(.heavy)
        .onReceive(model.$isFavorited, perform: { status in
            self.isFavorited = status
        })
    }
}
```

Here, you may notice, that you can't directly make the published property a getter and setter!

You have to actually provide a @State variable `isFavorited` *and* the observed object (aka `model`).

You also have to observe changes to the model's `isFavorited` and the update your @State variable `isFavorited` accordingly.

If you try to make it "short", i.e. only using the published property from the model and omitting the extra `@State` variable, your rendering logic will become flawed!

The third view is the `ContentView` which is the root view of your task:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let bird: Bird = .init(name: "Tweety")
    
    var body: some View {
        EnvironmentReader(\.env) { env in
            let isFavorited = IsFavorited(
                favoritsStore: env.favoritesStore,
                itemId: bird.id
            )
            BirdDetailFavoriteButtonView(
                model: isFavorited,
                bird: bird
            )
        }
    }
}
```

You may now think, this is convoluted. Me, too. But this is actually the minimal viable and robust solution.