# Publishing a Var from Another @ObservableObject During Init()

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding, initialization, swiftui-state

How does one publish a property from another `ObservableObject` which is created during initialization?

I want to ensure a specific property is captured as a `@Published`/`@Binding`/`@State` variable (so it's always kept updated in views), but I'm encountering an error when binding from an object that's *also* being created during the same `init()`. For example:

The `RandomOptionsManager` is an `ObservableObject` which loads a list of options from a file:

```
class RandomOptionsManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var listCount: Int = 0
    
    init() {
        // Real code would load the list from a file
        self.listCount = 150
    }
}
```

The `Randomizer` which uses it has a count property for how many options are available. I'm trying to get this as a `@Binding` from the `@Published` var in the options manager:

```
class Randomizer: ObservableObject {
    
    @ObservedObject var optionsManager = RandomOptionsManager()
    @Binding var listCount: Int
    
    init() {
        self._listCount = $optionsManager.listCount
    }
}
```

However, this code results in an init error:

> 'self' used in property access '$optionsManager' before all stored properties are initialized

What's the correct configuration to avoid this issue?

Comment: why can't you directly use `$optionsManager.listCount` wherever you need `listCount` ? There is no need of view to create another property when viewModel has it.

Comment: also there is no need of using a binding property here since you are not actually binding anything here.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. 
I did consider a calculated var to pass through the value, but if it's not defined as something subject to change, those changes wouldn't get automatically broadcast to any Views  observing /binding to the Randomizer, no?

Comment: view will be updated each time `listcount` is updated if your view directly used the `optionsManager.listCount` without binding

Comment: Binding as shown here doesn’t have any benefits just use it directly. Also you should be using StateObject to initialize. Environment isn’t available on init either.

Comment: @StateObject is a good callout, thanks, but if there's no Binding or State attributed to that property, how would views leveraging this object know when to update? Would having it as a calculated, pass-through property be enough, given that it wouldn't have a wrapper for the view to bind to?

Comment: SwiftUI understands `@Published` so it will update the view if the property changes.

Comment: So something like `var listCount: Int { optionsManager.listCount }` within the randomizer would be enough to ensure that Views update correctly?

Comment: Binding doesn’t tell Views to reload per say, Binding is a two way connection. If your issue is views not updating there is something else going on. SwiftUI decides when to reload views via different mechanisms you have to follow the rules of each.

Comment: ObservedObject inside a class is against the “rules”. ObservedObject only works in a View. All DynanmicProperty property wrappers with the exception of Published and AppStorage only work in a View.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78023270/binding-two-observableobjects-in-swiftui/78023415#78023415

Comment: Thanks. That `assign(to:)` was the key element I was missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the question comments, this can be solved by avoiding `@Binding` & `@ObservedObject` (which are really for views, rather than other classes like this) and using [`assign(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/assign(to:)) to republish the optionsManager's `@Published var` as a new property.

This only requires code changes for the `Randomizer` (the code for `RandomOptionsManager` remains unchanged):

```
class Randomizer: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var listCount: Int = 0
    private let optionsManager = RandomOptionsManager()
    
    init() {
        optionsManager.$listCount.assign(to: &self.$listCount)
    }
}
```

Note that `assign(to:)` automatically handles life-cycle management, so a separate explicit assignment to [`cancellable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/cancellable) is not required.

Comment: I think it should have stored in `Cancellable` to work.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. What is `Cancellable` and how does it apply here?

Comment: Your `optionsManager.$listCount.assign(to: &self.$listCount)` this binding requires cancellable. Because you are assigning the `Publisher` values to the variable `listCount`. This is actually same as using `sink`. Anyways it looks elegant but your this line should be as below:

`cancellable = optionsManager.$listCount.assign(to: &self.$listCount)`

Comment: Cancellable isn’t needed with this solution assign does all the work for you.

Comment: So Combine uses `cancellable` as some sort of reserved namespace for... publisher events which might be cancelled later?
Do you have a documentation link for more info?

Comment: Just look at the assign documentation you linked

Comment: Thanks @loremipsum, I didn't know this. For `sink` we need cancellable. `assign` itself stores the observation. I removed my answer as it is redundant.

Comment: Thanks. Got it! Added clarifying line to the answer to cover this.